# C# Date Format vs. Windows Date Format

Tags: c#, sql-server, date, date-formatting, string.format

Got a SQL Server database, having a table, with a column of type 'Date'.

When doing a select on the table via SQL Server Object Explorer in Visual Studio the value of the field returns as '2016-01-17', which is correct.

But when doing from C#

```
cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE id = '" + id + "';", conn); 
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    string dateString= String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}",((DateTime)reader[columnName]));
}
```

dateString comes out to be "01 17 2016" .. not the expected "01/17/2016"

I also tried:

```
string dateString = ((DateTime)reader[columnName]).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
string dateString = String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", (reader[columnName]));
```

But both comes out with the same result of "01 17 2016" without the forward slash.

One final test I did was just converting field to a string without format and it comes out as "Sun Jan 17 12:00:00 AM":

```
string val = reader[columnName].ToString();
```

^^I was about to ask you guys what the heck is going on, and then i remembered a couple days back I changed my Windows 7 calendar "short date" to format of "ddd MMM dd" (i.e. click calendar in systray and change date/time settings).

I don't want a user's windows date/time format to impact the function of how dates and times display in my C# or SQL Server code (its causing a number of things to break that rely on formatting).

What can I do to prevent this issue?

Comment: Have you tried using CultureInfo.Invariant so as to avoid user's Regional Settings configuration?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - i have not, i will google that and research -- i should prol take more care with date/time -- been lazy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a [date format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings), `"/"` is not a literal character, but instead represents [the locale's "date separator"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#dateSeparator).

Apparently, in your locale, the date separator is a space.

Per the linked documentation, you can escape it with single quotes to get a literal slash:

```
string dateString= String.Format("{0:MM'/'dd'/'yyyy}",((DateTime)reader[columnName]));
```

---

> (its causing a number of things to break that rely on formatting).

That's bad anyway — you should separate form and function. With that fixed, you can happily display dates to your users in the form with which they are most familiar, and in the form they would expect.

Comment: tl;dr When in doubt, read the docs! I'm not a C# developer and have never used these features; I just stumbled on your question and found the answer within a few minutes' of browsing the documentation for the functions you've used. They should have been your first port of call. Have fun!

Comment: looks like you're right -- i changed windows to "ddd/MMM/dd" and it works fine then.  the part of code i mentioned breaking was just a custom Method i wrote that checks if the date from a textbox (auto populated with that date from DB) is in valid format. since i hardcoded check for "/" it failed and wouldnt let me use the date to update the record.   i recall there is a way in C# to get the Date separator value (maybe its DateTimeFormatInfo.DateSeparator), ill scope that out and see if i can do my validation a different way so my code doesnt break this way